# DB::unprepared() does no raise exception on 2nd or later statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

in a Laravel application, I have a code that reads and executes an entire SQL file like so:

```php
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/seeds.sql'));
```

The file `seeds.sql` contains multiple SQL statements. Code works as expected and executes all the statements in the file, however, as soon as it encounters error (e.g. some typo), it will just not execute the rest of the file without throwing any exception.

I noticed that if I put each statement to its own `DB::unprepared()` call, it will raise the exception as expected, however, as soon as it is the 2nd or later statement in a single `DB::unprepared()` call, no exception is thrown and the remaining statements are silently not executed.

Could you recommend a way that will guarantee that all statements in a SQL file were executed if the code did not raised an exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, detected on a test on a new feature. I tried the same solution, calling each statement separately. If someone founds how to make it work I will apreciate it.

I ended up creating a method like such:

```php
    /**
     * Executes the given sql statements into the database in a transaction doing a
     * rollback if there is any exception. Avoids a problem of unprepared method, when it
     * has a wrong statement in the middle never raises an exception once the first
     * statement ir right.
     *
     * @param array $statements Sql statements.
     * @return bool @see hhttps://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_unprepared
     * @throws DuplicatedKeyDataException Trying to insert / update data with duplicated
     *                                    key fields.
     */
    public static function executeUnpreparedStatements(array $statements)
    {
        $conn = static::getConnection();
        $conn->beginTransaction();

        try {
            foreach ($statements as $sqlStatement) {
                $conn->unprepared($sqlStatement);
            }
        } catch (Exception $err) {
            $conn->rollback();

            if ($err instanceof QueryException && $err->errorInfo[1] === 1062) {
                throw new DuplicatedKeyDataException();
            }

            throw $err;
        }

        $conn->commit();
    }
```

Maybe you could so something like loading the file into memory (or reading it line by line) and then doing something like that.

Comment: where should I edit that method?